# Make cell imageView fly in with animation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can I make imageView property of my cells fly in one by one?

I can now make them fly in, but only all at once.

And is it good for performance to do something like this?

## Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `indexPath.row` to calculate a delay.

```
float animationDelay = 0.2f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f 
                      delay:animationDelay * indexPath.row 
                    options:0 
                 animations:^{
            cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        }  completion:^{}];
```

This will delay every row by 0.2 seconds relative to the row above it. Of course this will only work when you initially load the table, but I guess this is what you're trying to animate? When you start scrolling and new cells are loaded, you probably should set the delay to zero. Otherwise the images will take a while to show up.

To achieve this I recommend introducing a `BOOL` ivar called `loadingTheFirstTime` that is set to `YES` initially (in the `init` or `awakeFromNib` methods). Then you can set that to `NO` when the table is shown the first time. When creating the cells you should then check for this variable first to see if you have to add a delay.

Answer (score 2):

I supposed here that you are in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Change your animation with that :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 3.0 
                      delay: indexPath.row
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear 
                 animations: ^{
                     cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

The animations will load with 1 sec of interval. If you're not in this function, set a tag to your cells when you create them, and put that tag in the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set up a method where there is a for loop that runs through every cell and runs the animation for each time through the loop? Regarding performance, I have no idea. I would't imagine it would be GOOD for performance, especially if there are a lot of cells, but you can always try it and find out! :)